# Scrapy shell ignoring export SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, python-2.7, settings, scrapy

I've set the settings module envvar value to my_module.my_submodule.my_leaf_module. Inside is a number of constants set including a DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS dictionary. Anyway I set the above and run the scrapy shell against a sample URL I want without any spider specified. When it starts up there are no exceptions or warnings but my supplied settings module is not used.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the setting modules is loaded during shell. See the documentation below

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

It has no mention of it. What you can though do is create a DebugSpider and launch your url in that and invoke a debugging shell. So add below to your spiders code

```
class DebugSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "debug"

    def __init__(self, url=None):
        if url is None:
            raise Exception("Please specify a url using -a url=....")
        self.start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

Then from terminal run

```
scrapy crawl debug -a url="http://tarunlalwani.com"
```

This will load your settings module also and make the request and give you a same debugging shell

```
2017-09-12 00:16:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://tarunlalwani.com> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
>>> [s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x10562b748>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://tarunlalwani.com>
[s]   response   <200 http://tarunlalwani.com>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x106432c50>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that the `settings` referenced in the shell is a `Settings` object built from the `settings.py` file, and is not the `settings.py` itself.